# How to make a plain TeX conditional which checks if some specific numbers are present?

Tags: tex-core, conditionals

I need to make a simple conditional in a macro. If `#1` is "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", or "6", then print `Text: #1`, otherwise, do nothing, even if it is empty. I tried this code:

```
\ifnum#1=1
    Text:~#1
\if
```

I cannot even get make it able to check if `1` is present. How can I check `#1` is equal to "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", or "6"?

Comment: Is `#1` definitely an integer, or does the answer need to cover the case where it's not? Can it be an integer expression (such as `10 - 6`) and if so does that need to count?

Comment: Only `\macro{1}`, `\macro{2}`, `\macro{3}`, `\macro{4}`, `\macro{5}`, and `\macro{6}` should count as a match. Something like `\macro{15}` should not count as any match. Usually, the macro is empty, like `\macro{}`, I guess is why my code is getting confused.

Comment: Should `\macro{\really\wild\input}` be taken into account?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your comments you indicated that #1 can be empty

```
\ifnum#1=1
    Text:~#1
\if
```

would be an error in that case but a simple change to

```
\ifnum0#1=1
    Text:~#1
\if
```

will make an empty argument be Ok (and count as zero). beware that `\macro{ 1}` would then be an error as `\ifnum0 1=1` does not work as `0 1` is not a valid number. It's possible to insert extra macros to remove spurious spaces if that is needed.

```
  \ifnum0#1>0
     \ifnum0#1<7
        Text:~#1
    \fi
  \fi
```

Comment: From the way the question is phrased, I'd interpret the comparison as essentially string-based (it has to be exactly as given). You could easily get rid of the spaces with `\numexpr`, or as you say using a macro-based approach. My worry with the `\numexpr` solution is that something like `1 + 1` would then be valid, but the question suggests it's not.

Answer (score 3):

For a limited range of integers, with the other possibilities as blank or integer input, I would go with

```
\catcode`\@=11 %
\long\def\@firstoftwo#1#2{#1}
\long\def\@secondoftwo#1#2{#2}
\long\def\macro#1{%
  \ifnum 0#1 > 0 %
    \ifnum 0#1 < 7 %
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
```

used as

```
\macro{}\TRUE\FALSE
\macro{0}\TRUE\FALSE
\macro{1}\TRUE\FALSE
\macro{6}\TRUE\FALSE
\macro{7}\TRUE\FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope that I understood your question correctly:

```
\def\myempty{}
\def\mynumber#1{%
\if#1\myempty
\else
\ifnum#1>0
\ifnum#1<7
Text:~#1
\fi\fi\fi}
This is \mynumber{0} \mynumber{4} \mynumber{7}
\end
```